# json gzip compression with php

Tags: php, json, gzip

I use this way to send serve a json file from my server.

```
$data = file_get_contents('cache/file.json');

ob_start('ob_gzhandler');

// Output as normal
echo ($data);
```

cache/file.json is not gzip compressed (plain json, without spaces the whole
file is one long row).

I'm thinking Instead of gzipping the file everytime it is requested.
Should I store it as a gzipped file

```
$gzjson = gzencode($data, 9);
file_put_contents('gzcache/file.json', $gzjson);
```

So I will minimize the server load? 
The idea is to gzip it and everytime the file is requested
just serve the already gzipped file and not gzip it every time it's requested.

Does anyone think this is a good idea?

Comment: The answer depends very much on how big the file is and how often you request it.

Comment: The max file size (uncompressed) would be 200kb. 
Isn't it a better practice to compress it once and serve the compressed file
everytime is requested?

Comment: I suggest that you edit your question.  @Marged is absolutely correct and his considerations are key elements to your question.

Comment: It's beacuse the file will be requested many times that I want to implement less server resource intense method. It's obvious isn't it? If I read it just once I wouldn't bother gzipping it in the first place.

Comment: So lets say the file is 200kb uncompressed and 100kb compressed and will be read about 10k times a day.

Answer (score 1):

As your php sands some CPU load to generate zip so it mean - **Yes** it is good idea to have it cached and just read it instead if you have enough space on server.

Additionally you can implement old cached files remove logic. Check if file creation time( with http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php )

```
$creationTime = filemtime($zip);

if(time() - $creationTime >= 60 * 60 * 24 * 2) // 2 days
   @unlink( $zip );
}
// create new zip
```

and if it older then some range(2 days) delete it and regenerate it again, so it mean you will regenerate that file once per range

Comment: The cache time is not a problem. Because I will fetch it from an API
and once I download the json from the api I will gzip it and store it immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I would let httpd to serve the json as a static resource. The server should take care about content negotiation and return archived file, if client can unpack it.